# Q&A: How to get a minting token id?

Tags: transactions, tokens, ethereum-classic

**This part of own Q&A serial of posts which shares knowledge gained during work on one project**

It is not obvious about how to get a just minted token id. You may assume there would be a transaction on chain which could be queried and token id could be extracted then from it, but is there other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ERC721 standard allows to have Enumerable interface which gives access to token ids.

Although, there is well known security attack on its concept and implementation by overusing `balanceOf()` call (or may be something different).

Another option is query events for this contract and search of returned results for pair user-tokenId.

Finally we can store a minted token id in the separate special storage by extending own `ERC721` contract implementation.